# How does Windows recognize my machine as desktop, when showing "Preparing your desktop"

Tags: windows, boot

I was installing Windows 7 on my friend's desktop machine. Once it was installed, it showed the screen "Preparing your desktop":

[image]

How does Windows recognize the machine as desktop/laptop at first use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not. Your desktop is the environment you work in (the main explorer window without borders, with the trashcan, with the start button, the [my computer] icon, the taskbar, etc etc).

This 'desktop' is used on both laptop computers, desktop computers, towers and 19" rack computers.

Comment: well, thats not entirely true (that windows doesn't know if its on a 'laptop'), but you are correct, in this case the op is definitely conflating the differant meanings of "Desktop" in their image. Windows can retrieve this information from the BIOS DMI infomation via WMI in the Win32_SystemEnclosure namespace. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156537.aspx

Comment: @Frank, in case you're considering to post that as an answer, then revert the changes I made to the title of the question :-)

Comment: @FrankThomas feel free to edit my question

Comment: I don't have anything substantive to add that Hennes and Ramhound haven't covered, and its hardly worth points so a comment will suffice for anyone searching for how to determine chassis type on Windows. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> How does windows recognize my machine as desktop/laptop at first use?

**It does not.**  The message is indicating that the user profile has never logged into the system before, and the `Desktop` ( more specifically the actual folder for that specific user ) for the profile has to be created.

Of course Windows can tell the difference between a desktop and a laptop, but how that is done, has nothing to do with the image you have provided.